# Trouble Updating MySql Table from Visual FoxPro Table

Tags: mysql, sql, insert, foxpro

I have a Visual FoxPro table that I am using to update a MySql table, the layouts are identical. My insert statement is:

```
SQLEXEC(comm,[INSERT INTO unpaid (sms, salesman, ourinv, date, custcode, customer, custpay, amtpd) values(?k_unpaid.sms, ?k_unpaid.salesman, ?k_unpaid.ourinv, ?k_unpaid.date, ?k_unpaid.custcode, ?k_unpaid.customer, ?k_unpaid.custpay, ?k_unpaid.amtpd)])
```

there are 4 more columns that I need to update but when I include them in the above statement I get "Command contains unrecognized phrase/keyword"

The additional columns are:

custpay
salescom
totcust
totcom

Again, the table structures are identical, I have tried adding all 4 of the columns and I get the error, I have tried adding just one of the additional columns to the query and still get the error.

Comment: it is probably the ? in ?k_unpaid

Comment: Please edit your question and write the statement that works and the one that doesn't

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that the instruction you're passing is longer than the permitted quoted string length. Try building the string first and then passing it to SQLExec() as a variable. The easiest way is with the TEXT command:

```
TEXT TO m.cSQL
INSERT INTO unpaid (sms, salesman, ourinv, date, custcode, customer, custpay, amtpd) values(?k_unpaid.sms, ?k_unpaid.salesman, ?k_unpaid.ourinv, ?k_unpaid.date, ?k_unpaid.custcode, ?k_unpaid.customer, ?k_unpaid.custpay, ?k_unpaid.amtpd)
ENDTEXT

SQLEXEC(comm, m.cSQL)
```